# Why there are so many NSNotification during iOS BLE communication and how to release them?

Tags: ios, memory, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

iOS experts, is there anyone who hit a memory leak when using iOS bluetooth low energy framework?

We found that there are so many Notification with 16KiB object posted during Bluetooth communication, but they're not released automatically as we observed.

We'd like to release those objects, otherwise it will hit OutOfMemory when we continuously communicate with our device in a short period.

We're appreciated if someone can provide any clue to release those objects or avoid receiving/creating those objects.

See below image about leaks with 16KiB object.
[image: Instruments memory look]

Comment: I'm wondering if you forgot to release some other objects.

Answer (score 2):

The image (screenshot) you show, shows no memory leaks. It just shows allocations.
Where are the memory leaks you are seeing?
Also, showing some code helps

Update: by "shows no memory leaks" I mean that

1. Of the two rows in Instruments, you have selected the first/upper one, which shows *allocations* **not leaks**, and
2. The second row, leaks, has only green checkmarks, indicating there are no leaks.

Profiling your app with Instruments is not easy. Go find some good videos and learn how it works - just like we all did

Comment: Please add this in comment. Its not answer.

Comment: I disagree with the fact it doesn't answer the question. If we check the screenshot, there is no memory leak (it's all green). Only allocations by system. It may lack a little of explanations, but it still true.